# Refresh JIRA OSGi bundles

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, jira-plugin

What's the proper way to refresh jira OSGi bundles?

Should I use Felix OSGi console on runtime (not available on my JIRA instance by default) ?

Comment: I assume that this is related to your previous question about optional imports. How are you installing/updating the bundle in question? If this is via some kind of UI or command built-in to JIRA, and if JIRA is failing to call refresh when they do that, then it's a bug.

Comment: Yes it is related to my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888475/optional-bundle-resolution). I'm using JIRA UI and it is failing after refresh. The only way it works is to stop JIRA, install JAR's manually and start JIRA, but this is cumbersome at development level. Thats why I asked this question to verify my suspicions.

Comment: You can also programmatically refresh from your own bundle: `getBundle(0).adapt(FrameworkWiring.class).refreshBundles(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing from the Gogo shell is equivalent to the following code, which you can put into your own bundle:

```
context.getBundle(0).adapt(FrameworkWiring.class).refreshBundles(...)
```

So perhaps you can listen to the bundle events when new bundles are installed by JIRA UI, and call refresh using the above method.

The trick is to do the refresh only when JIRA has finished a series of installs/updates/removes. Only JIRA can really know when it is done, but perhaps you can do the refresh after waiting, say, 10 seconds after the last change.

Comment: Thanks for a hint which might be helpful - I will check this out.